# Ubuntu 20.04: can't cut (ctrl +x) from desktop or paste a cut element directly to it (ctrl + v)

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, clipboard

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I've had this issue for ages but just now it's been affecting my productivity and I decided to look for an answer.

Basically, I can't <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> from desktop or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> a cut element directly to it. It simply does nothing.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> do work fine.

All commands work fine in other contexts as well (Chrome browser for example) so I know it's not a keyboard related issue.

A weird thing that I noticed regarding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is that if I'm inside a file explorer window and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> from there and then paste the cut element into another file explorer window that is sitting on /Desktop, it does work as intended.
It is just cutting/pasting directly from/to the Desktop that does not work.

Are there any commands that may have disabled that functionality whatsoever?

Any help would be appreciated.